# Вставка данных в таблицу TableView в момент выполнения программы (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

**Суть проблемы**: создавал я значит интерфейс через SceneBuilder, там я сразу добавил таблицу TableView и присвоил ей id, сохранил все и добавил реализацию класса контроллера. Везде на все возможных руководствах по тому, как создавать таблицу показывают, что нужно сначала создать таблицу, потом добавить данные и ВРУЧНУЮ добавить в родительский узел для отображения на самом экране. Но в моем случае подразумевается добавление не изначальных данных, а по ходу выполнения. Т.е. когда у меня есть тот самые объект TableView я пытаюсь в момент выполнения программы добавлять новые столбцы, скажем, в обработчике события нажатия кнопки. И нечего абсолютно не добавляется, возможно это связанно с тем, что я пересоздаю объект перед тем, как что-то туда добавить, ибо необходимо передать в конструктор таблицы коллекцию с элементами для заполнения.

**Мой код**

```
package sample;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem addElement;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> table;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
         addElement.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
             @Override
             public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                 ArrayList<Person> per = new ArrayList<>();
                 per.add(new Person("Dima", 10));
                 per.add(new Person("Ivan", 10));
                 ObservableList<Person> collection = FXCollections.observableArrayList(per);
                 table = new TableView<Person>(collection);

                 TableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Имена");
                 nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name"));
                 table.getColumns().add(nameColumn);

                 TableColumn<Person, Integer> ageColumn = new TableColumn<>("Возраст");
                 ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Integer>("age"));
                 table.getColumns().add(ageColumn);

             }
         });

    }
}
```

Из кода видно что я добавляю некого Person в таблицу, при этом необходимо создать новый объект для передачи элементов для отображения с коллекции типа Person. Тут еще один интересный момент, если мы не создаем при этом новый объект таблицы, то просто отобразится название колонок, а если создать новую таблицу с данными, то вообще нечего не отображается.

**Код класа Person**

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.*;

public class Person {

    private SimpleStringProperty name;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty age;

    public Person(String name, int age){
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name.get();
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age.set(age);
    }
}
```

Comment: По идее не нужно перезаписывать таблицу `table = new TableView<Person>(collection);`, просто добавляйте данные и колонки в существующую таблицу (причем попробуйте сначала добавлять колонки, а потом данные).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблем в коде вижу несколько.

1. Не надо пересоздавать tableView - это ни к чему. У вас уже есть таблица на гуе, используйте ее
2. При нажатии кнопки addElement у вас не должны создаваться новые колонки (не вижу смысла в этом). Создайте колонки один раз и заполняйте содержимое таблицы.

Таким образом, ваше метод `initialize` будет выглядеть примерно так

```java
@FXML
void initialize() {
    //один раз создаем колонку Name и добавляем ее
    TableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Имена");
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    table.getColumns().add(nameColumn);

    //один раз создаем колонку Age и добавляем ее
    TableColumn<Person, Integer> ageColumn = new TableColumn<>("Возраст");
    ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("age"));
    table.getColumns().add(ageColumn);

    // на каждый клик создаем нового Person и добавляем в таблицу
    addElement.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("Dima " + random.nextInt(1000), 10));
        persons.add(new Person("Ivan " + random.nextInt(1000), 10));
        table.getItems().addAll(persons);
    });
}
```